# Find the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{\log_{x^2}(x)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

I do understand that x should belong to $(0,1) \cup (1, \infty)$ but when I solved it I got three conditions: that $x$ belongs to $(1, \infty)$ , $(0, \infty)$ and $x\neq1$. So upon intersection of these intervals I am only left with $x$ belonging to $(1, \infty)$. So problem is that I am not getting $(0,1)$ as a solution.

Here's how I solved it:
1/2 log x to base x>=0 .......(i) 
Therefore x>=1 
This implies that x belongs to [1, infinity) 
x cannot=1 .......(ii)
And
X >0
Therefore x belongs to (0, infinity)
Upon intersection of these 3intervals I get x belongs to (1, infinity)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If you want to know where you went wrong, you'll need to show a bit more details. You say you solved for three conditions, but we can't see what those conditions were and which interval belongs to which condition.

Comment: I have edited the question... Plz check

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in (0, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$, then observe that:
$$
\log_{x^2}(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(x^2)} = \frac{\log x}{2\log x} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
which is never going to be negative, as it is a constant. So if we put the above function inside a square root, we don't need any further restrictions on the domain to ensure that we never take the square root of a negative number.